need add physic ammojs and babylonjs (glb models)
I want to set my tera model as a map landscape, but tree goes through it.
I use babylonjs and ammojs-typed.
I need help, don't know what to do.
What I need is for the tera model to be a physical body that other meshes will not pass through. I also want the geometry of my models to be used.
    private async game(): Promise<BABYLON.Scene> {
        this.scene.useRightHandedSystem = true;
        const ammo = await Ammo.call(this);
        this.scene.enablePhysics(
            new BABYLON.Vector3(0, -9.81, 0),
            new BABYLON.AmmoJSPlugin(true, ammo)
        );

        const camera = new BABYLON.ArcRotateCamera(
            'camera',
            Math.PI / 2,
            Math.PI / 2,
            10,
            new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
            this.scene
        );
        camera.attachControl(this.canvas, true);

        const light = new BABYLON.DirectionalLight(
            'light',
            new BABYLON.Vector3(1, -1, 0),
            this.scene
        );
        light.intensity = 0.7;

        const shadowGenerator = new BABYLON.ShadowGenerator(1024, light);

        BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh(
            '',
            'src/static/models/',
            'tera.glb',
            this.scene,
            function (meshes, particleSystems, skeletons) {
                for (const i in meshes) {
                    meshes[i].checkCollisions = true;
                    console.log('check', meshes[i].checkCollisions, i);
                }
                const policecar = meshes[0];
                policecar.scaling.scaleInPlace(0.1);
                policecar.physicsImpostor = new BABYLON.PhysicsImpostor(
                    policecar,
                    BABYLON.PhysicsImpostor.MeshImpostor,
                    { mass: 0, friction: 0.1, restitution: 0.9, shape: policecar }
                );
            }
        );

        BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMesh(
            '',
            'src/static/models/',
            'tree_dry.glb',
            this.scene,
            function (meshes, particleSystems, skeletons) {
                for (const i in meshes) {
                    meshes[i].checkCollisions = true;
                    console.log('check', meshes[i].checkCollisions, i);
                }
                const policecar = meshes[0];
                policecar.scaling.scaleInPlace(0.1);
                policecar.physicsImpostor = new BABYLON.PhysicsImpostor(
                    policecar,
                    BABYLON.PhysicsImpostor.MeshImpostor,
                    { mass: 10, friction: 0.1, restitution: 0.9, shape: policecar }
                );

            }
        );

        this.engine.runRenderLoop(() => {
            this.scene.render();
        });

        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            this.engine.resize();
        });

        return this.scene;
    }
}


I tried different meshimposters, but nothing works

I need your help, I'm junior in game ged, and need your thinks
